# Internal Error 500 : IIS8 error in server but does not show error details on web page in browser

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

My web page was on a Windows Server 2003. When I change my server to Windows Server 2012 (IIS 8) my web page (that was written in Visual Studio 2010) in last server show over internet but since I change my server it just show this error:

> Internal error 500.

I do not know how can i fix it?I change my web config but it dose not change

Comment: Write `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your web.config file. Or, call the website from a browser directly on the server itself (connecting via RDP).

Comment: i do that but it dose not solve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `web.config` file add the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will ensure upstream errors are rendered to the browser.

Comment: Thank you so much, this sorted out my problem. I was bashing my head to wall for few weeks ... Even the Microsoft guys and *professors* couldn't figure it out!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem on a new Windows 2012 Server.

In IIS manager, at the site level, I had also set properties for ASP for **send errors to browser** to true, but was still getting the generic message in my browser (I am accessing the site from another PC, not locally on the server).

I went into error pages, and clicked 'Edit Feature Settings' to find this dialog window:

[image: Edit Error Pages Settings Dialog]

Change setting from 3rd option: **Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests**
To 2nd option: **Detailed errors**

Answer (score 1):

Open your website in browser on server or modify your web.config file to allow showing error on client browser

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
```

Then it should give more detail about this error.

Or you can check your server event log.

Comment: I guess you should set it to "Off" instead of "On".

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

`Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Error"`